# venv pyproject.toml did not run succesfully

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

To get this out of the way I have tried this with the newest version of Python(the code I wish to run was not written for it), I have updated wheel, and pip is also the latest version

I am on windows 10
I'm trying to run Python code that needs to be run in a virtual environment. I'm doing it all through the PowerShell command line. My friend has it working using Python 3.8 on windows 10 which is what I am using. I have a TXT file which contains all the versions of the libraries that are needed to run the program.

```
arlpy==1.7.0
dicttoxml>=1.7.4
jsonpickle==2.0.0
matplotlib==3.3.2
numpy>=1.19.4
pickleshare==0.7.5
scipy>=1.5.3
virtualenv==20.0.31
xmltodict>=0.12.0
```

I am able to create a virtual environment, but I cannot install the required dependencies without getting an error. It's an extremely long error message that begins with

```
 `Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
```

I get this error when I use the commands

```
enter code here

pip install -r requirements.txt
or
pip install arlpy==1.7.0
or
pip install matplotlib==3.3.2
```

I have Python 3.8 and 3.11 installed but when I type Python in PowerShell it tells me I'm using version 3.8.

I will post the full error message in all its glory below

```
(kek) PS C:\Users\Peter\desktop\sound-localization-simulator-master\env> pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting arlpy==1.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached arlpy-1.7.0.tar.gz (43 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: dicttoxml>=1.7.4 in c:\users\peter\desktop\sound-localization-simulator-master\env\kek\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonpickle==2.0.0 in c:\users\peter\desktop\sound-localization-simulator-master\env\kek\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.0.0)
Collecting matplotlib==3.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (8.3 MB)
Collecting numpy>=1.19.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Obtaining dependency information for numpy>=1.19.4 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/57/8d328f0b91c733aa9aa7ee540dbc49b58796c862b4fbcb1146c701e888da/numpy-1.24.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl.metadata
  Using cached numpy-1.24.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl.metadata (5.6 kB)
Collecting pickleshare==0.7.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
Collecting scipy==1.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Using cached scipy-1.6.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (29.5 MB)
Collecting virtualenv==20.0.31 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached virtualenv-20.0.31-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 MB)
Collecting xmltodict>=0.12.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
  Using cached xmltodict-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
Collecting utm>=0.5.0 (from arlpy==1.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached utm-0.7.0.tar.gz (8.7 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pandas>=1.0.1 (from arlpy==1.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Obtaining dependency information for pandas>=1.0.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/ae/26a2eda7fa581347d69e51f93892493b2074ef3352ac71033c9f32c52389/pandas-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl.metadata
  Using cached pandas-2.0.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting bokeh>=1.4.0 (from arlpy==1.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached bokeh-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 MB)
Collecting certifi>=2020.06.20 (from matplotlib==3.3.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Obtaining dependency information for certifi>=2020.06.20 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/dd/2234eab22353ffc7d94e8d13177aaa050113286e93e7b40eae01fbf7c3d9/certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib==3.3.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib==3.3.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Obtaining dependency information for kiwisolver>=1.0.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/e1/597068727a76cbaf6aadb28882eb4d0ac48fed2e00a37e9f6cbbca5c24df/kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl.metadata
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp38-cp38-win32.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0 (from matplotlib==3.3.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached Pillow-10.0.0.tar.gz (50.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 (from matplotlib==3.3.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Obtaining dependency information for pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.3 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/92/8486ede85fcc088f1b3dba4ce92dd29d126fd96b0008ea213167940a2475/pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from matplotlib==3.3.2->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.19.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached numpy-1.22.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (12.3 MB)
Collecting appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 (from virtualenv==20.0.31->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.1 (from virtualenv==20.0.31->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Obtaining dependency information for distlib<1,>=0.3.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/a0/9ba967fdbd55293bacfc1507f58e316f740a3b231fc00e3d86dc39bc185a/distlib-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached distlib-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0 (from virtualenv==20.0.31->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Obtaining dependency information for filelock<4,>=3.0.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/45/ec3407adf6f6b5bf867a4462b2b0af27597a26bd3cd6e2534cb6ab029938/filelock-3.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached filelock-3.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
Collecting six<2,>=1.9.0 (from virtualenv==20.0.31->-r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=2.9 (from bokeh>=1.4.0->arlpy==1.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1 (from bokeh>=1.4.0->arlpy==1.7.0->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0.tar.gz (13.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l062pcfs\contourpy_badeebcceee343a2b9915118603870a3 C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l062pcfs\contourpy_badeebcceee343a2b9915118603870a3\.mesonpy-0ejhyovi\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l062pcfs\contourpy_badeebcceee343a2b9915118603870a3\.mesonpy-0ejhyovi\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l062pcfs\contourpy_badeebcceee343a2b9915118603870a3
      Build dir: C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l062pcfs\contourpy_badeebcceee343a2b9915118603870a3\.mesonpy-0ejhyovi\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: contourpy
      Project version: 1.1.0
      Activating VS 17.6.4
      C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.36.32535 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.36.32535 for x64")
      C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.36.32535.0
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Program python found: YES (c:\users\peter\desktop\sound-localization-simulator-master\env\kek\scripts\python.exe)
      Did not find pkg-config by name 'pkg-config'
      Found Pkg-config: NO
      pybind11-config found: YES (C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-97s7g6no\overlay\Scripts\pybind11-config.EXE) 2.11.1
      Run-time dependency pybind11 found: YES 2.11.1
      Configuring _build_config.py using configuration
      Need python for x86_64, but found x86
      Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried sysconfig)

      ..\..\src\meson.build:5:10: ERROR: Python dependency not found

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l062pcfs\contourpy_badeebcceee343a2b9915118603870a3\.mesonpy-0ejhyovi\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

The file
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l062pcfs\contourpy_badeebcceee343a2b9915118603870a3.mesonpy-0ejhyovi\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
does not exist

I looked for pyproject.toml on my computer and I only found this

[image]
[image]

I will also share with you what is inside of my virtual environment folder

[image]
here are the contents of the .CFG file
[image]

the inside of the scripts folder
[image]

inside of Lib\site-packages

[image]

inside of the include folder
[image]

I hope this wasn't too much information I appreciate your help because I'm very confused

Comment: The code formatting error was right. It's intentional and correct that it was blocking you from posting. Please don't post code as an image. Follow the advice in your screenshot and post any code (including error tracebacks and shell commands) as _formatted_ text.

Comment: I notice that inside pyvenv.cfg both the 'home' and 'version' settings are pointing to python 3.8. Try pointing that to you python 3.11 location.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update I removed all Python off of my computer and reinstalled it and then it worked!!!!!!!!

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).